Derivation of the formula for intensity of sound wave
I was trying to derive the formula for finding the intensity of the sound wave, after deriving it in my way i am missing a factor of 2 in the formula, Can I know what I am doing wrong ?
Here is my approach to derive it.

Symbols:

$I \ldots$ Intensity of sound wave,

$u \ldots$ speed of sound in air

$f \ldots$ frequency of sound wave

$D \ldots$ density of air

$s \ldots$ amplitude of vibration



Let's say that the wave is being transmitted through a specific closed space with cross sectional area $A$, so the power supplied through that cross sectional area is $P=I\cdot A$,
After $t$ seconds energy contained in the volume $(A \cdot u \cdot t)$ is $E=(I \cdot A \cdot t)$ that is the energy which crossed the cross sectional area $A$ in $t$ seconds.

My assumption here is that all of the energy is taking the form of kinetic energy of the vibrating particles,
So we calculate the kinetic energy,
Which is $\tfrac{M}{2} v^2$, where $M$ is mass of air contained in the enclosed space and $v^2$ is the average value of $v^2$ .
$$M=D \cdot A \cdot u \cdot t \; .$$
$$v=2\pi fs \cos(wt-kx) \; ,$$
which is partial derivative of $s$ with respect to $t$. Average value of $v^2=2\pi^2 f^2 s^2$, because average value of $\cos^2$ is $(1/2)$.
Therefore the kinetic energy, is equal to
$$K.E=\frac{1}{2} \, DAut 2\pi^2 f^2 s^2$$
Which is equal to $E$. So,
$$DAut \pi^2 f^2 s^2 = I \cdot A \cdot t$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{I = \pi^2 f^2 s^2 D u}$$
Which is contradictory to the actual answer that is
$$I= 2\pi^2 f^2 s^2 Du$$

Please use MathJax to typeset your equations.

I rewrote your question using MathJax as "paulina" pointed out justly. Please check if they are correct, i.e. if I did not import any error accidentially.

I got the answer , energy is stored half in the kinetic energy of particles vibrating due to the sound wave, and half in the 'potential energy' which is not actually potential energy in ideal gases, it is the kinetic energy due to random motion of the gas molecules, which can be treated as potential energy,  considering both these energies ,we can reach to the right answer. For clarification refer : Potential energy in ideal gas due to sound wave
